# Which products contain Monster, PC, or NPC tokens for Dnd4e?

Tags: dnd-4e, monsters, tokens

Which books/boxes/etc contain sheets of tokens and or maps for Dnd4e?  I have the monster vault, which I believe came with tokens, and the outdoors and indoors tiles I think came with some tokens also, but I'm not sure.

But what other ways are there to get lots of monster tokens for Dnd4e (that come with associated monsters and rules)?

**clarification:**  I'm not looking for minis, just the round cardstock/cardboard tokens and tiles or maps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Cribbed from my comment in your other [question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/8712/what-monster-tokens-are-these)]

**The two starter sets** - the 2009(?) one, and the Red Box

I believe they have the same sheet of monster tokens. Both have one monster pic on one side and a different monster on the flip side.

**The Essentials DM Kit and Essentials Monster Vault**

The DM Kit token images should match up with monster pictures in the module from the box.

The Monster Vault token images should match the images in the book from the box.
The flip side of the tokens has a bloodied version of the monster (but does not name the monster).

**The Gloomwrought boxed set and the Monster Vault: Threats to the Nentir Vale boxed set**

Both have tokens where the flip side is a bloodied version of the monster, and where the bloodied side of the monster has the monster name.

The two starter sets and the DM kit also contain PC/NPC tokens. These all have bloodied and non-bloodied sides.