# What monster tokens are these?

Tags: dnd-4e, monsters, tokens

Here is a snap shot of some monsters that I found while being bored today.  I couldn't identify what the monsters were (sort of).

[image: Monster Tokens]

the monster on the top left marked (3) turns out to be a "Vampire minion" according to my monster vault, however, I don't believe them :)  What else is that icon of? Is it a Deuger? a Drow dwarf? A zombie? Something else?

The rest of the images I assume are bullywigs of one form or another (I'm guessing this because I own the Iron circle module, and bullywigs are in one of the fights. However, I didn't notice any pictures, so I don't know which bullywig is which, and I couldn't find any mention of bullywigs in my monster vault.  Any assistance of what these monsters are, and perhaps where I got them or any other info would be handy thanks.

FYI, I don't have DDI subscription so I can't see links to the compendium.

Comment: The products that I can think of that have tokens are the two starter sets - the 2009(?) one, and the Red Box - I believe they have the same sheet, and both have one monster pic on one side and a different monster pic on the other while all other token sets are bloodied versions of the same monster on the back; the Essentials DM Kit and Monster Vault, for the former, the monster pics are in the module, and for the latter the monster pics are in the book; and Gloomwrought and the new Monster Vault, both of which have monster names on the back.

Comment: hmm ok that helps narrow it down a bit.  However, all these tokens are just "bloodied" on the back side, and I couldn't find the monsters (except the vampire, but really those are vampires?) in the Monster Vault.  Do you remember which module comes with the DM Kit?

Comment: Reavers of Harkenwold is the module. The (5) token and the bottom most token are from the DM Kit, the others I'm not sure of

Comment: Ok, just found the Reavers of Harkenwold books 1, where the bullywigs are mentioned,   but no pictures. I did find that there are a few pages with different monster stats for slightly different frog based creatures. (pages 20-22 for those following along at home) Now to figure out which ones are supposed to be which.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Bullywugs are from this image from Monster Manual 2, page 29. I found it on the web with descriptive data on [Wikia](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Bullywug):
[image: Bullywugs]

Having played the encounter, I believe the correct mapping of types, from left to right is:

- Bullywug Croaker
- Bullywug Leaper    (Twitcher in MM2)
- Bullywug Chieftain (Mud Lord in MM2)
- Bullywug Mucker

The frog head token is Sporeback Frog from Monster Manual 3, page 91 - though in the module it's meant to represent the "Giant Frog".

***[UPDATE:]*** Added the details from the comments, especially @Ravn. Thanks to everyone for the pointers and be sure to vote-up Ravn's comments...

Comment: Great find! thanks, where is the information in the wikia is from?  I especially like this paragraph:  A particular point of interest involving the species was discovered by Brother Twick of Verdusk, a halfling cleric of Chauntea. It seems that bullywugs are irresistably drawn to ale and either die or lapse into a coma when they drink it (depending on the amount consumed). Bullywug attacks have become increasingly rare in the lands surrounding the marshes where Bullywugs live since those settlements have started keeping a keg of ale ready simply in preparation for attacks from the creatures.

Comment: It's from Monster Manual 2, page 29. From left to right, they're Croaker, Twitcher, Mud Lord and Mucker.
Mucker is a level 1 brute, Croaker is a level 3 minion/brute.

Comment: The frog creature that isn't on the picture above (one of the ones labeled '2') is the Sporeback Frog (level 2 controller) from Monster Manual 3, page 91.

Comment: Thanks Ravin, can you put those comments into an answer, and also include where the weird vampire minion comes from?

Comment: I think Farmer got everything! (except Leaper = Twitcher and Chieftain = Mud Lord)
I don't know where the vampire is from, I looked through all vampire, zombie, drow and duergar entries in the Monster Manuals and even a few of the character portraits.

I do, however, agree that it looks nothing like a vampire.

Answer (score 2):

The bullywug tokens are included in the Dungeon Master's Kit, as creatures mentioned in the Reavers of Harkenwold module. One of those beasts should be (according to the module) a giant frog. If I had to bet, I'd say the grey one with the red tongue on the second row, second column. I'd say the others are a mucker, a leaper and a croaker, because the bullywug chieftain has an unnumbered token in that kit at least.

Comment: To clarify: there isn't a place where the creatures are shown with images and names in the DMK. But still, since there are two unnumbered froglike beasts, and two bullywug "leaders" (the chieftain Gloorpk and the champion Uggloor), I'd say these aren't them.